# Spyder - stop consoles accidentally closing

Tags: python, spyder

When I use Spyder, I have fairly frequently accidentally closed the wrong consoles. Usually by a cmd+W. Most applications ask if I want to save before close/confirm I definitely want to close. Spyder just closes, so I may lose training that's been occurring for an hour, say, by a single click or keyboard typo, and I cannot find a way to get it to ask before it does close a console.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you closing the IPython console within Spyder itself or do you mean you closed the terminal window that you used to start up the entire IDE?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `hist -g` in the console to get your history back.

And you could do this:

Tools > Preferences > General > Advanced Settings

check `Prompt when exiting`

Comment: @Socorro Is this a answer to your question or didn't I understood your issue?